# Undefined symbol: zend_type_to_string

Tags: php, xdebug, archlinux, php-7.4

I'm a bit new on ArchLinux but I have installed PHP 7 with pacman and after that Xdebug but Xdebug install the package php ( that is PHP 8 ).

When I tried to launch PHP 7 I got the following message and Xdebug doesn't work:

> PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: `/usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so` (`/usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so`: undefined symbol: zend_type_to_string), `/usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so.so` (`/usr/lib/php7/modules/xdebug.so.so`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

That's my `/etc/php7/conf.d/xdebug.ini`

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
;xdebug.remote_enable=on
;xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.start_with_request=yes
;xdebug.mode=debug
```

So if someone have the solution :)

Comment: Looks like the Xdebug version that you have installed does not match the PHP version. try re-installing it. P.S. Have a look at this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66966952/783119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263429) !

```
$ asp update xdebug
$ asp export xdebug
```

After that i updated the `PKGBUILD`

```
$ cat PKGBUILD 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maintainer: Sergej Pupykin <pupykin.s+arch@gmail.com>
# Maintainer: Jonathan Wiersma <arch aur at jonw dot org>
# Contributor: Jonathan Wiersma <arch aur at jonw dot org>
# Contributor: sracker <smb.sac@gmail.com>

pkgname=xdebug-php7
pkgver=3.0.2
pkgrel=2
pkgdesc="PHP debugging extension for php7"
arch=('x86_64')
url="https://www.xdebug.org"
license=('GPL')
depends=('php7')
backup=('etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini')
source=("https://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-${pkgver}.tgz"
    'xdebug.ini')
sha256sums=('096d46dec061341868d3e3933b977013a592e2e88992b2c0aba7fa52f87c4e17'
            '7c66883dc2ade69069ef84e30188b25630748aa9c8b0dd123727c00505421205')

build() {
  cd "$srcdir"/xdebug-${pkgver}
  phpize7
  ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-xdebug
  make
}

package() {
  cd "$srcdir"/xdebug-${pkgver}
  make INSTALL_ROOT="$pkgdir" install
  install -D -m 644 "$srcdir"/xdebug.ini "$pkgdir"/etc/php7/conf.d/xdebug.ini
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

And then i did that
`makepkg -s  -i -r`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

So, I uninstalled PHP 8 and installed Xdebug for PHP 7.4:

`yay -S xdebug7`

Comment: This answer gave me hint to my solution. I have mutiple php installed and when I was installing xdebug it was setting it up for current php i.e. 8 so had to simply Say, `apt-get install php7.4-xdebug`

This might save some hours for someone. thanks!